# canopy linux running error: missing libmkl_intel_lp64.so

Tags: linux, enthought

I am a paid user and I have installed canopy on a red hat server and got the virtual environment configured. In the virtual env, python is the one contained in the environment:

```
    (User) $ which python
    ~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
```

But when I cannot import "numpy" from python:

```
    (User) $ python
    Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Mar 25 2013, 15:55:17)
    [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import numpy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
        import add_newdocs
      File "/usr/lib/canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
        from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
      File "/usr/lib/canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
        from polynomial import *
      File "/usr/lib/canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 17, in <module>
        from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
      File "/usr/lib/canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
        from linalg import *
      File "/usr/lib/canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
        from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
    **ImportError: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

I tried to update numpy with enpkg, but the above error still shows up when importing numpy.

```
    (User) $ enpkg numpy
    prefix: /home/wchen06/canopy_virtual
    MKL-10.3-1.egg                                                     [fetching]
     74.60 MB [.................................................................]
    numpy-1.6.1-5.egg                                                  [fetching]
      3.33 MB [.................................................................]
    MKL-10.3-1.egg                                                   [installing]
    248.04 MB [.................................................................]
    numpy-1.6.1-5.egg                                                [installing]
     11.20 MB [.................................................................]
```

Please help.

Comment: Please feel free to email for installation support as described in your welcome email. We can probably address this issue more quickly that way.

Comment: It looks as if there is some confusion in your manually configured virtual environment. Since you were apparently able to run the Canopy GUI (since it created your User venv), there was actually no need to set up any additional venv manually. In your email, please describe as best you can the sequence of steps that you performed. After we've clarified this offline, we can sum up back here for benefit of anyone else with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply! This is due to a bug in Canopy 1.0.0 (beta) for Linux. For a workaround, please see https://support.enthought.com/entries/21656595-ImportError-libmkl-intel-lp64-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file